# NullReference Exception C# during database entary

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I Have an Exception of Null Reference at combobox value. I allow null in database. But It not works. What should I Do? I mention the Exception Area in the comments: Here is my Source code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into mytable (userid, password, gender) values (@userid, @password, @gender)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());//Here is exception line (NullReference Exception)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Clone();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Added");
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are nearly always really easy to track down, and you did! So the answer is easy: something is nothing. You need to check whether or not an item is selected, since `comboBox1.SelectedItem` can be `null`.

So, ...

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null) {
```

Or, ...

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0) {
```

Generally you would have some validation that prevents it coming to this.

Comment: Thanks. It's works. But if I want to add null value from Combobox to Database then Why I handle It?

Comment: @TahirAziz That's a different thing, you _can_ insert `null` quite freely if your database supports it; what you _can't_ do, in .NET, ever, is access _members_ of a `null` thing, which is what you're doing here. So, check for `null` before accessing members, and if `null` then insert that, otherwise use the value.

Comment: @TahirAziz if you want the value to be null in DB then you want something like: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", comboBox1.SelectedItem == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

if `comboBox1.SelectedItem` is null, you cant call the `ToString()` function. (thats your error)

use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", comboBox1.SelectedItem == null ? null : comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```